# How do I add a bipolar stepper motor to this circuit?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, wiring, polarity, bipolar

I have just started electronics at school and cannot find any tutorials on how to do this. I am creating a circuit that when the light intensity increases a bipolar stepper motor will step clockwise for with 5 second intervals for 30 seconds then do the same but anti clockwise. I know how to program this, but not how to connect it to my circuit. How would I connect this to my circuit with the use of h bridges. I am using circuit wizard. circuit diagram btw, this is just a circuit, I am not planning on making this I would just like to know for further use.[image][image] I would like to connect it to Q4 (no output is there currently )

Comment: Why have you reposted this question? What was wrong with the old one? Is it fixed in this one?

Comment: No sorry it wasn’t allowing me to edit the last one.

Comment: What do you want the light sensor threshold to be 300uA * 10k = 3V at 10 Lux? I don’t think so, unless you are using a large panel.  How many steps and what acceleration and velocity do you wish when the light turns on? This must be specified.

Comment: I just need to know how to connect the bipolar stepper motor to this circuit

Comment: what is the purpose of Q1 and D2?

Comment: You can’t, unless you answer my questions

Comment: Oh okay sorry I’m new to this.  Basically, when you turn this circuit on the LED turns on, Q1 is just an indication that the circuit is on. Plus it’s a genie 08 not all outputs have to be in use.

Comment: What do you mean by "this is just a circuit"?

Comment: "I just need to know ... to this circuit" With the level of detail you're giving **us**, the level of detail we can give **you** is to take any one wire from the motor and solder it to any one wire in the circuit.  That's probably not what you **want**, which is why we are all trying very hard to get you to please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just connect it to your Q4 to get any useful behavior.  You need to do one of two things: get a stepper controller (or controller + driver), and drive it's enable, direction, and clock pins from three pins on the microcontroller.  Or, get a stepper driver and drive its enable, phase A, and phase B pins from the microcontroller.  Either way you need to understand the needs of the stepper (or controller) and meet them.

Comment: That's all I needed, thank you! Sorry if I wasn't clear I'm 15 and very new to this.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!